# redmine migrated to an onther debian9

Tags: ruby, debian, redmine

i migrated my redmine from ubuntu server
to an debia server
so i moved the /usr/share/redmine folder,
the /var/cache/redmine folder,
the /etc/redmine folder,
the /etc/apache2/sites-availble folder
and i did the apache vhost things

but i got this error when i try access to redmine:

```
Started GET "/login?back_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmaster.evey.live%2F" for 197.244.16.191 at 2022-07-13 16:54:46 +0000
Processing by AccountController#login as HTML
  Parameters: {"back_url"=>"https://master.evey.live/"}
  Current user: anonymous
  Rendering account/login.html.erb within layouts/base
  Rendered account/login.html.erb within layouts/base (30.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 190ms (ActiveRecord: 35.8ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (unknown keywords: permitted_classes, aliases):
    11: <%= favicon %>
    12: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.0', 'application', 'responsive', :media => 'all' %>
    13: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'rtl', :media => 'all' if l(:direction) == 'rtl' %>
    14: <%= javascript_heads %>
    15: <%= heads_for_theme %>
    16: <%= call_hook :view_layouts_base_html_head %>
    17: <!-- page specific tags -->

app/models/user_preference.rb:50:in `initialize'
app/models/user.rb:952:in `pref'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1493:in `javascript_heads'
app/views/layouts/base.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_layouts_base_html_erb__1784490353953904667_47324072699360'
lib/redmine/sudo_mode.

rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```